# use emulator with android firebase sms authentication

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase authentication service to authenticate users using SMS.

I read on [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) that :

> Also, note that phone number sign-in requires a physical device and
>   won't work on an emulator.

The question is how do I continue to develop using the emulator without the verification? How do i force authentication or any other method to continue development ?

Answer (score 17):

Yes. It is **possible** but only with **testing phone numbers**.

Go to your

**`firebase console -> Authentication -> SIGN-IN Method -> Phone`**

and check the "Phone numbers for testing (optional)" field.

[image: Firebase Console]

Comment: Then how can we write the logic from app side for test phone number? I mean how can we validate

Comment: Just consider that you got OTP and the OTP is whatever you specified. For logic correctness check the firebase logs for error. The OTP will be only validated only if you call the firebase API correctly, So it will help you.